# SVG coordinates on click after pan and zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm blocking on a stupid thing, I'm looking for SVG coordinates after on click. But my SVG can be zoomed and moved.

This example will talk more I think :

http://blockbuilder.org/Servuc/36931fc3950218df024d0aa7ff8c8d3c

I want the coordinates of under the black circle. **IMPORTANT** : The black circle is just a position indication, in my case in click somewhere on SVG.

I've read that : [D3 click coordinates after pan and zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054728/d3-click-coordinates-after-pan-and-zoom) but it didn't help me.

EDIT : I mean if the black circle is on the left, I get X and Y, I move the black circle on right, I get the same X Y
Have a good coding day !

Answer (score 0):

It was so simply ...

First, you should get some informations :

- SVG.getScreenCTM()
- Translation *X* and *Y*
- Scale
- Client click coordinates ( `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` )

**IMPORTANT** : Use *parseFloat*, not *parseInt* ;)

```
function screenToSvg(x, y, translateX, translateY, scale) {
    var myScreenCTM = $("svg")[0].getScreenCTM();
    return {
        x : ( x - myScreenCTM.e - translateX ) / scale,
        y : ( y - myScreenCTM.f - translateY ) / scale
    }
}
```

To get translations and scale values, use : `/.*translate\((-?\d+(.\d+)?),(-?\d+(.\d+)?)\)( scale\((-?\d+(.\d+)?)\))?/` with `$1` `$3` and `$6`.